# Checking OneDrive connectivity with C#

Tags: c#, .net, onedrive

I am trying to perform a very basic connectivity check against the OneDrive windows client.

I've been toying around with the Live SDK but that generally leads me down the path of authorizing the user and establishing a session. I am not interested in any upload/download functionality and do not need to integrate OneDrive within my app. This leads me to think that the SDK is not the proper route to go down.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a connectivity check, you probably want to the network connection profile calls that are available in .Net, e.g.:

```
            ConnectionProfile internetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (internetConnectionProfile == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CanPerformODOperations: not connected to Internet");
                return OneDriveStatus.noInternetConnection;
            }

            if (App.Settings.UnrestrictedDownloads)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CanPerformODOperations: app settings set to unrestricted downloads");
                return OneDriveStatus.OK;
            }

            if (internetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() != NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CanPerformODOperations: not got Internet access");
                return OneDriveStatus.noUnrestrictedNetwork;
            }

            ConnectionCost cost = internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost();
            if (cost == null || cost.NetworkCostType == NetworkCostType.Unrestricted)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CanPerformODOperations: cost is null or unrestricted");
                return OneDriveStatus.OK;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("CanPerformODOperations: not got an unrestricted network");
            return OneDriveStatus.noUnrestrictedNetwork;
```

where I define OneDriveStatus as:

```
    public enum OneDriveStatus { unknownProblem, noInternetConnection, noUnrestrictedNetwork, OK };
```

I only attempt a login if I get OneDriveStatus.OK back from those calls.